# Использование буквы "e" в записи чисел Java

Tags: java

В других языках таких как JS, PHP, Python запись чисел с использованием буквы e не вызывает никаких трудностей

```
const number = 1e6
// Будет равно 1 000 000
```

но в Java

```
public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 1e6;
}}
```

Выводится:

```
java: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
```

Причём с числами с плавающей запятой никаких ошибок не возникает. Но с целыми...

```
double a = 1e6;
//Сохранится как 1000000.00.
```

Кто может объяснить почему так, как это исправить?

Comment: И в js/php/python нет ведь строкой типизации переменных. А вы попробуйте это в c++ и c#. Проверил для питона `1e6` - там тоже вещественный тип `print(1e6) # 1000000.0` + `print(type(1e6)) # <class 'float'>`

Comment: *"possible lossy conversion from double to int"* - текст ошибки как-бы намекает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что такое выражения - это представление вещественного числа, а присваивание вещественных чисел в целые может привести к потере данных, поэтому это нужно явно делать:

```
int a = (int) 1e6;
System.out.println("a: " + a);
// a: 1000000
```

Подобные числа можно еще в таком виде описывать:

```
int b = 1_000_000;
System.out.println("b: " + b);
// b: 1000000
```